# I cannot access a server on my laptop despite opening up the port for inbound rules in Firewall and checking AP Isolation

Tags: networking, server, xampp

This problem has been driving me crazy for about 4 months now. I have searched all across the wide web and found no answer that could help me. I want to set up a local server (like http-server or Jellyfin) and access it on a local network. I have tried a lot of solutions and tried just using the basic tutorial on the Jellyfin website in case it was a simple problem.

This didn't solve it, so I followed advice on opening up ports in the firewall but that still didn't work. I then turned off the firewall completely and it still wouldn't allow me to access the server from other devices. I then saw something about AP Isolation but I couldn't find that setting on my Huawei HG8245c router.

The strange parts are this:

Firstly, I could access my Jellyfin media on my LG WebOS SmartTV but not from other devices.

Secondly, if I turn on the wireless hotspot on my laptop and connect devices up to it, I could access the servers with no problem.

Any help at all would be very kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am the most retarded person on the planet and I don't know how I missed the port-forwarding.

To fix it, I port forwarded port 8080 to one of the IP's of my laptop.

Edit: After trying this on another router it didn't work but it is an old router so I believe it can be solved by getting a better router.